# Get current locale programmatically in magento2

Tags: magento2, stores

I want to get current language of store. When I switch store as per store vise I want to get store language.

How can i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface` to get locale code

```
/**@var \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface **/
protected $_store;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface $store,
  .....
) {
  $this->_store = $store;
}
```

you can check like this :

```
$this->_store->getLocaleCode() == 'en_EN';
```

Hope this code useful for you.

Answer (score 3):

Get your current store language scope using below way,

```
 public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver $locale
        ) {
            $this->locale = $locale;
        }
```

call inside phtml file,

```
$currentCode = $this->locale->getLocale();
if($currentCode == 'en_US'){

}
```